# numba: real uint16 data type?

Tags: python-3.x, type-conversion, overflow, numba

I am converting a checksum function from C to Python.

The input payload, *data*, in Python is of type *bytes*

*length* : usually it is *len(bytes)*; can be a lower value.

```
import numba
import numpy as np

@numba.jit(nopython = True)
def checksum(data: bytes, length: np.int32, init: np.uint32) -> np.uint32 :
    s1 = np.uint16(init & 0xffff)
    s2 = np.uint16(init >> 16)
    i = 0
    while i < length :
        s1 += data[i]
        i += 1
        s1 = ...   # omitted the math operations, for clarity
        s2 = ...
    return  (np.uint32(s2) << 16) | s1
```

The problem: in C the two variables s1 and s2 are declared as uint16 so even if during the computations there are intermediate values bigger than 0xffff, s1 and s2 never overflow.
This is how the algorithm has to work.

With Numba I sadly discovered that *np.uint16* is probably a hint for the JIT, not the real variables data type.

When the intermediate computation values surpass 0xffff also s1 and s2 surpass 0xffff (I presume they are promoted to uint32), so the final checksum is obviously incorrect.

Question:
How to declare s1, s2 as C uint16 ?

In general: in Numba, is it possible to declare integer data types strongly typed, like C data types?

Comment: 1) The type hints are useless in Numba. 2)You can see the types with `ckecksum.inspect_types()` on a already compiled function. 3) You can explicitly set the type for local variables with `@nb.njit(locals={"s1": nb.uint16, "s2": nb.uint16}`)

Comment: "With Numba I sadly discovered that np.uint16 is probably a hint for the JIT, not the real variables data type." No. This is because an assignment is simply not a declaration. Neither in CPython nor in Numba. Numba can promote the type of the variable based on a unification mechanism. For example, if you write `a = 1` and later `a = np.log(a)`, then Numba will declare `a` as a `float64` variable since it was first an integer but the `log` returns a `float64`. This is done that way because people do not care much about types in Python and the Numba codes are statically typed unlike Python ones